# Unable to install kur on win10 due to scipy

Tags: python, pip, deep-learning

I'm trying to install kur on my laptop running windows 10 and when installing files, it needs scipy 0.18.1, which it is unable to install. With a bit of googling, it seems that scipy cannot be installed on windows 10.
This is the error message I get.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Anthony\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1g1t9lgj\scipy\
```

Any ideas as to workaround this?

Comment: I have scipy on Win10. There must be more to this.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the version of scipy 0.19 that fits my system from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy.
Then I installed kur from the wheel file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kur/0.3.0.

I can't check it because I have no idea how to use it but it did appear to install properly and I can import it.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Could you explain what to do with the .whl file from scipy and how to install kur using wheels? I'm a beginner to python and dont quite understand what im doing.